# xcode. После авторизации пользователя в firebase не срабатывает переход на view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
     
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
//
        
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if user == nil{
                print("нужно авторизоваться!")
    
            }else{
                print("пользователь зарегистрирован!")
                let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
//                newViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // это значение можно менять для разных видов анимации появления
//                newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // это та самая волшебная
                self.window?.rootViewController?.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
                print("so what?")
            }
        
        }
        
        return true
        

    }
```

В консоли принтует все сообщения, т.е. проверка проходит успешно и пользователь зарегистрирован, но переход на "MainViewController" почему то не срабатывает.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.present(newViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

на

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = newViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло...